# PHP Curl Error code 25

Tags: php, curl, ftp, egnyte

I tried to search the web but I couldn't find a clear point on the issue I'm trying to figure out.

I have a situation where the uploaded files will be sent over to another server via FTP (Egnyte). I have a localhost setup and it succeeded uploading the files to FTP but not in the live site where it gives me a curl error (25)  - in FTP, STOR command has been denied. It has a further error message of "Failed FTP upload: 451". What bugs me even more is, the server has staging / dev cloned from the live site and it perfectly works there.

What could be in the localhost setup that I should look in the server of the live site and/or possible causes of the curl error? Curl is enabled in the live server btw.

My curl options (considering variables are supplied properly and ftp has been connected):

```
// connection options
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $username . ':' . $password,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // don't verify SSL
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_FTP_SSL        => CURLFTPSSL_ALL, // require SSL For both control and data connections
        CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH     => CURLFTPAUTH_DEFAULT, // let cURL choose the FTP authentication method (either SSL or TLS)
        CURLOPT_UPLOAD         => true,
        CURLOPT_PORT           => $port,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,
    );
```

and here's my upload function:

```
public function upload( $file_name, $file ) {

    // set file name
    if ( ! curl_setopt( $this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url . $file_name ))
        throw new Exception ( "Could not set cURL file name: $file_name" );

    /* Open the file for writing  */
    $file_stream = fopen($file, "r");

    /* Open a memory for writing */
    $stream = fopen('php://temp' , "wb");

    /* Read the file and write it to the stream 1kb at a time */
    while ($data = fread($file_stream, 1024))
        fwrite($stream, $data);

    // rewind the stream pointer
    rewind( $stream );

    // set the file to be uploaded
    if ( ! curl_setopt( $this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_INFILE, $stream ) )
        throw new Exception( "Could not load file $file_name" );

    // upload file
    if ( ! curl_exec( $this->curl_handle ) ) {
        throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Could not upload file. cURL Error: [%s] - %s', curl_errno( $this->curl_handle ), curl_error( $this->curl_handle ) ) );
    }

    // close the stream handle
    fclose( $stream );
    fclose( $file_stream );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this issue 2 weeks ago.

It seems like in the live site, it fails when there are spaces in the filename. For now, replacing the spaces with underscores should be good. Not yet sure though why its perfectly fine to have spaces when I integrated the script in the localhost setup.